# Prevent exe file from being closed/Crash windows os if a program is closed

Tags: python, windows, exe, bsod

I'm trying to achieve something ; I created a exe file, that automatically force shutdown the computer at 11 pm.
I would like to make this script impossible to stop or crash, or even make the entire system crash if the program is closed.
How can i achieve this ?

Note :
I'm on a laptop, running windows 10. I made a python file, and i converted it in an exe file with py installer. Then i created a shortcut to that exe file that run the program with admin rights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mark the process as critical Windows will trigger a blue screen crash if that process is stopped/killed.

There is information about how to do this [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43405/Protecting-Your-Process-with-RtlSetProcessIsCriti)

Note: Although it is possible to do this, it is not a good idea to do so. For example as suggested by Anders, use a Scheduled Task. Having the system crash could result in information loss, or other unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Windows service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services?redirectedfrom=MSDN). You can deny Administrators trying to stop/pause the service, that should slow them down a little bit.

Or since we are talking about triggering something at a specific time, you might want to use the task scheduler instead.

In any case, you will never fully lock down something like this from an Administrator since they can always take ownership and modify the ACL.

Comment: Ok thank you.
But if any administrator can take back permissions, and then stop the service, it is not really unstoppable ? Is there no way to set the service with 'system' permission, to prevent administrators modifying it ? In safe mode or anything like that ?

Comment: Don't let untrusted users have administrator permissions.